# How to know in which environment we are from a collection definition?

Tags: docpad

I would like something like the following pseudo-code :

```
collections:
    posts: function (database) {
        var match = env === 'debug' {layout: 'post', published: true} ? {layout: 'post'};
        return database.findAllLive(match, {date:-1});
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `this.docpad.getEnvironments()` (JavaScript) or `@docpad.getEnvironments()` (coffeescript) which returns an array on environments we are currently using. Based on your code intentions you then want to check if `debug` is inside of it.

In JavaScript as you're using:

```
collections: {
    posts: function (database) {
        var match = this.docpad.getEnvironments().indexOf('debug') != -1 then {layout: 'post', published: true} ? {layout: 'post'};
        return database.findAllLive(match, {date:-1});
    }
}
```

In the standard CoffeeScript

```
collections:
    posts: (database) ->
        match =
            if 'debug' in @docpad.getEnvironments()
                {layout: 'post', published: true}
            else
                {layout: 'post'}
        database.findAllLive(match, {date:-1})
```

It's also worth mentioning, that you may also be interested in `docpad.getDebugging()` which will return a boolean reflecting the inclusion of the `-d --debug` CLI flag.

Comment: Thanks ! However, `getEnvironments()` seems to be the way to go (`@docpad` being undefined)

Comment: Hrmm, maybe docpad is the scope of the collection functions. I should probably make that behave more like the plugins. Glad you got it working :)